# Switching between sprites in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been working on a game in unity for a school project. Currently I'm trying to make a countdown before my game starts. I'm sure this is basic knowledge but I'm fairly new to Unity.

This is my Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class StartScreen : MonoBehaviour {

    static bool sawOnce = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        if(!sawOnce) {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;
            Time.timeScale = 0;
        }

        sawOnce = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(Time.timeScale==0 && (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) ) {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;

        }
    }
}
```

I want to change between three different sprites before "Time.timeScale = 1;" and after "GetComponent().enabled = false;". Each sprite should just show for a second before the next one shows up.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new function with a wait statement.
Something like this would work.

```
void Update () {
    if(Time.timeScale==0 && (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) ) {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        changeSprites();
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;

    }
}
    IEnumerator changeSprites(){
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = SPRITE1
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = SPRITE2
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = SPRITE3
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Add a semicolon ; after each sprite line. And obviously change SPRITE1 to the actual sprite. Sorry for forgetting about it